# What are best activation and regularization method for LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm, regularization, activation-function

In `Keras` there are:

```
activation: Activation function to use (see activations). Default: hyperbolic tangent (tanh). If you pass None, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: a(x) = x).
recurrent_activation: Activation function to use for the recurrent step (see activations). Default: hard sigmoid (hard_sigmoid). If you pass None, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: a(x) = x).
```

For activation functions and

```
kernel_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the kernel weights matrix (see regularizer).

recurrent_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the recurrent_kernel weights matrix (see regularizer).

bias_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the bias vector (see regularizer).

activity_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the output of the layer (its "activation").
```

For regularization methods that we can choose from:

```
keras.regularizers.l1(0.)
keras.regularizers.l2(0.)
keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01)
```

Or define our regularization method. It also is possible to add `dropout()` layer after our `LSTM` layers:

```
keras.layers.Dropout(rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
```

And maybe the other methods that I don't know. But which `activation` and `regularizaion` is more suitable for `LSTM`? Is it a good idea to add regularization to the `LSTM` or it hast regularization property inside it's cell by default?

Comment: I think dropout is the best regularization method for any deep learning algorithm, but for the activation function, in LSTM mostly sigmoid and tanh are used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which method will be best speaking generally. Still, I like to cross-validate my model's performance using KerasRegressor wrapper from the SciKeras module with scikit-learn's RandomizedSearchedCV ( +KFold ).

I've learned this method from Machine Learning Mastery: https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/

Generally, it is better to play around with possibilities and resolve problems through experimentation than deductively. Deep learning is math, but due to the complexity and raw computation power at hand instead of solving problems theoretically before designing an experiment, You can just go straight to experimentation.

Below is my code, used for a BullionPredict project (predicting gold daily gold close price data):

1. You create a function that will generate models for KerasRegressor:

```
def create_LSTM_model(learning_rate=0.001, units=32, dropout=0.2, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid'):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(InputLayer( input_shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,)))
  model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)))
  model.add(LSTM(
      units=units,
      activation=activation,
      recurrent_activation=recurrent_activation,
      dropout=dropout, ))
  model.add(Dense(OUTPUT_SHAPE, activation='linear'))

  model.compile(
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
      loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
      metrics=['mse', 'mape'])
  return model
```

You should include hyperparameters You want to tune as function parameters.

2. You create KerasRegressor object.

```
model_5 = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_LSTM_model,
                         verbose=0,
                         learning_rate=0.001,
                         activation='tanh',
                         units=16,
                         recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                         dropout=0.2)
```

3. You define parameters that include not only model building/compiling hyperparameters, but also can include training hyperparameters, like nr of epochs or the batch size.

```
params = {'activation': ["relu", "tanh", 'elu', 'sigmoid'],
          'recurrent_activation': ["relu", "tanh", 'elu', 'sigmoid'],
          'dropout': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8],
          'batch_size': [16, 32, 64],
          'units': [16, 32, 64, 128],
          'epochs': [50, 100],
          'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]}
```

4. You create RandomizeSearchCV object and fit it.

```
random_search_5 = RandomizedSearchCV(model_5,
                                   param_distributions = params,
                                   cv = KFold(3),
                                   n_iter=30,
                                   n_jobs=-1,
                                   scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                                   return_train_score=True,
                                   error_score='raise')
random_search_results_5 = random_search_5.fit(train_price_feats, train_price_labels)
```

5. Then You can use Your random search dictionary to perform some Exploratory Data Analysis and draw conclusions Yourself. If You have more time and or computational power You can also use GridSearchCV instead of RandozmizedSearchCV.

Cheers!